# What is the reason for Dwarka to be destroyed specifically by Flood?

Tags: mahabharata, gandhari, curse

From [Mahabharatha](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11024.htm) :

> "Gandhari said ... Since deliberately, O slayer of Madhu, thou wert indifferent to this universal carnage, therefore, O mighty-armed one, thou shouldst reap the fruit of this act. By the little merit I have acquired through waiting dutifully on my husband, by that merit so difficult to attain, I shall curse thee, O wielder of the discus and the mace! Since thou wert indifferent to the Kurus and the Pandavas whilst they slew each other, therefore, O Govinda, thou shalt be the slayer of thy own kinsmen! **In the thirty-sixth year from this, O slayer of Madhu, thou shalt, after causing the slaughter of thy kinsmen and friends and sons, perish by disgusting means in the wilderness.** The ladies of thy race, deprived of sons, kinsmen, and friends, shall weep and cry even as these ladies of the Bharata race!’"

- This explains Mother Gandhari cursing Lord Krishna and his Entire Yadhava Race to be destroyed in 36 years.
- There is No Mentioning of destroying Dwarka City and cursing it to be flooded.
  **MY QUESTION :**
- As Mother Gandhari didn't said it to be flooded why Dwarka city was destroyed by flood and is submerged in sea ?
- Is there reason for destroying dwarka specifically by flood ?

Comment: Then how to destroy Dwarka if not by flood?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria The Lord can kill them by using theives who battled with arjuna, war with other kingdoms ,even battle between them as like in sea shore,by sages but why flood was used and IMO the dwarka buildings were also destined to be destroyed so he used it

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Mother gandhari cursed lord krishna and his yadhava race to be killed  If yadhavas were killed then  curse is finished.Population will come with other race as ALL YADHAVAS are killed. This question is about yadhava race and we dont need to care whether dwarka place is to be forest or with asuras,rakshasas or any other race kingdoms

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Lord destroys only according to karma so his will also turn's to be according to karma.This is what  I am asking what karma that caused specifically dwarka to be destroyed by flood ?

Comment: One possible reason can be that Dwaraka was a gift to Krsna by Varuna when he needed a new Kingdom. So as soon as Krsna ascended back to Vaikuntha, the land was once more reclaimed by Varuna.

Comment: @Surya friend there are chances for your prediction to be correct

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria friend yes god has power to destroy but the question is why should he do it as the entire universe is just a spark of his energy so why should he want to destroy dwarka especially and why should with a flood

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Nice answer lets see him and ask him